# How to get queryset with .filter(ifsc_startswith) , where ifsc is input value, in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class BankViewSet(PaginateByMaxMixin,viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed.
    """
    queryset = Branches.objects.filter(ifsc__startswith='')
    serializer_class = BranchSerializer
    pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['ifsc','branch','city','district','address','state']
    filterset_fields =['ifsc']
    ordering_fields = ['ifsc']
    max_paginate_by = 100
```

I have this view of my API. I thought `filter(ifsc_startswith)` parameter will return queries starting from input values but to my surprise it doesn't. Instead it shows results like filter(ifsc_contains).

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify with a circumflex that the search should look for strings that *start* with the given search value, so:

```
class BankViewSet(PaginateByMaxMixin,viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    # …
    search_fields = ['^ifsc','branch','city','district','address','state']
```

This is specified in the [documentation of the **`SearchFilter`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter):

> (…)
>
> The search behavior may be restricted by prepending various characters
> to the `search_fields`.
>
> - **`'^'` Starts-with search**.
> - `'='` Exact matches.
> - `'@'` Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's PostgreSQL backend.)
> - `'$'` Regex search.

Comment: althought using ^ifsc in filterset field gave error. so I applied ^ifsc in search_fields

Comment: @JaySardar: sorry I meant the `search_fields` ... Somehow I mixed that with the `filterset`.